# Passing Boolean powershell parameters from a non-powershell terminal

Tags: powershell

Sometimes I invoke powershell scripts from Linux bash/shell scripts like so:

```bash
pwsh MyScript.ps1 win-x64 false
```

And in my `MyScript.ps1` file, I set up parameters like so:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $runtime,
    [Parameter()]
    [bool] $singleFile = $true
)
```

I get an error for the second parameter:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'singleFile'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
```

I tried passing `'$false'` as well as `0` but it treats everything as a string. When invoking powershell scripts from outside of a PWSH terminal, how do I get it to coerce my string-boolean value into an actual Powershell boolean type?

Comment: In fact your code is working with : 
`& '.\Sans titre1.ps1' toto -singleFile 1`. I had it a the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose to use [[switch]](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2)

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $runtime,
    [Parameter()]
    [switch] $singleFile
)
Write-Host $runtime
```

It works  for me with :

```
pwsh ".\MyScript.ps1" "toto" -singlefile
```

In fact your code is working with :

```
pwsh ".\MyScript.ps1" toto -singleFile 1
```

Comment: I love this. It doesn't answer my question, but I'm OK with that since it's apparent that my approach is wrong.

Comment: My code is not working on Windows when I execute the following  using Git Bash: `pwsh MyScript.ps1 foo 0`.

Comment: @void.pointer When called like this, `0` will be passed as a string, which doesn't convert to `[bool]`. Only actual numeric literals, which you can only define by PowerShell script, do convert. Try this: `pwsh -command "& {.\MyScript.ps1 foo 0}"`. Of course, you could also just write  `pwsh -command "& {.\MyScript.ps1 foo $false}"`.

Comment: @zett42, note that here's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected. In other words: `pwsh -c ".\Myscript.ps1 foo 0"` will do, for example.

Comment: @zett42 I'm marking this as the answer, so thank you. I think it would be helpful to amend your answer to include your solution (with the more concise syntax described by @mklement0). Thanks to you both!